# SwiftUi what is the best way to number rows once you have a model

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that gets data from an API what I want to do is rank rows based on points from highest to lowest (I am able to do that now) however issue is that I want to show row number like #1, #2 etc .. as you can see from below image in the red background it says 1 2 for both rows instead of the first saying 1 and the second row saying 2 . This is my code below . I have put a comment of **// issue is here** which is were the problem lies . As you can see I'm already using a forEach that passes in api data . Is there a way I can use that foreach  **ForEach(result)** and number the rows from 1...n and still be able to retrieve the data like I'm doing . I have seen examples of people doing that but it is usually for a simple string array . Any suggestions would be great .

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                let result = model.sorted {
                    $0.points! > $1.points!
                }
             
                ForEach(result) { value in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  Spacer()
                    HStack {
                    
                       ForEach(0..<result.count) { i in
                        Text("\(i + 1)")
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.red)
                       } // issue is here
                          
                        Text(value.initials!)
                         .fontWeight(.bold)
                             .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                         .foregroundColor(Color(SystemColorPicked(picked: value.color)))
                             .padding()
                             .overlay(
                                 Circle()
                                 .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4)
                                 .padding(6)
                             )
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                            Text("\(value.fullname ?? "NA")")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text("\(value.points ?? 0) | points")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a `ForEach` running within in item of your *other* `ForEach`.  The second one is the one that is displaying "1 2" each time, since it iterates through all the results every time.

I don't have all of your code, so I'm not sure what type `results` is, but here's a sample that you can adapt to your use case. Keep in mind you'll be doing this to the outer (ie first) `ForEach` loop:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var results = ["Test1","Test2","Test3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(results.enumerated()), id: \.1) { (index, value) in
                Text("\(index + 1) \(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on:

1. For the `ForEach`, I'm using `results` (or, `result` in your code) `.enumerated` -- this gives an index/item pair. I'm wrapping it in `Array()` because otherwise the `ForEach` won't want to take that specific type of sequence.
2. ForEach has to have an `id` -- here I'm just using the `String` itself. For your purpose, it might be different. `.1` refers to the second item of the tuple (ie the item, not the index)
3. In the `ForEach` closure, you now get `index` and `value`